# Can Adwords Remarketing and GA4 tags share the same event names in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I am trying to properly plug in GA4 events through Google Tag Manager for the upcoming transition away from UA. I had never questioned this in the past but I am now wondering - **Can GA4 and Google Adwords Remarketing tags share the same events without issue?**

For instance, both my Adwords Remarketing event and a GA4 Purchase event result in two purchase events in Tag Assistant and I am unsure if this will cause problems in the future.

[image]

Both of these events are being called separately via gtag events referencing the same event names.

**GA4 Purchase - Purchase Event**

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    currency: 'USD',                                            //currency
    transaction_id: gtagOrder.transaction_id,                   //order number
    value: parseFloat(gtagOrder.value),                         //revenue
    affiliation: gtagOrder.affiliation,                         //label
    shipping: parseFloat(gtagOrder.shipping),                   //shipping
    discount: gtagOrder.discount || 0,
    coupon: gtagOrder.coupon || '',                             //coupon
    tax: parseFloat(gtagOrder.tax),                             //tax
    items: gtagOrder.items,                                     //items
});
```

**Google Adwords Remarketing - Purchase Event**

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    value: value,
    items: gaEventObj.items
});
```

Right now to keep things simple, I've only used the exact event names mentioned in the documentation for both Adwords Remarketing and GA4.

Comment: I would add send_to parameters, so each only goes to the destination they are intended for. I believe the required items parameters are different.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll make sure to do this.